How to Sign an InnoSetup uninstaller
Today we use a pre-signed uninstaller file to get the uninstaller to be signed. In our .iss file this is by using "SignedUninstaller=yes" and "SignedUninstallerDir=Sign" and we place the pre-signed file in the "Sign" folder.
Now we want to switch to use SignTool instead since we want to set the version and this requires us to resign every build since the signature now changes.
All examples I have seen use a local sign tool. Instead I want to use an internal signing server IT has set up, we already sign the installer using a curl call to the server with the finished setup file. Anyone has an example for how we could write something like "SignTool=curl ..." in our .iss file? We are not using the script editor to give it a name since this must be done on a specific build server, so setting up a path locally makes no sense.
Or maybe it is possible to point SignTool to a script and put the signing there?
Not sure on how to use SignTool beside setting up the command using the Script Editor and then use the name in our .iss file, which is what all examples I have found so far does it.
BTW using Inno Setup 6.1.2

Would help, if you show us how exactly are you using curl to sign an exe. Though in general, the syntax of the "sign tool" configuration would be the same as with the actual signtool.

What kind of signing server do you use? A CSC API implementation? A HSM hosted by a cloud provider? Something else?

I have tried a different solution where I try to build to generated the .e32 pre-generated uninstaller. Then I wanted to sign it, and build again, should work in theory I think. But we use docker contains, and everytime I try to move or sign or modify the .e32 in any way, i get permission denied. Tried to use sudo but that didn't help.

I do not think you have answered any of our questions.
